# Does this situation indicate that $g(x)>f(x)$?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for $0<x<5$. By calculating the first and second derivatives I see that both functions are increasing and concave (not strictly concave), i.e. $f''<0$ and $g''<0$. Then If I have $$f(0)=g(0)=0$$ and $$f(5)=10\quad ,\quad g(5)=11.$$ Then, does this prove that $g$ is always grater than $f$?

Comment: No.  Let $g(x)=11-\frac{11}{25}(5-x)^2$ and $f(x)=10-10(\frac{x}5-1)^{1000}$, for example.

Comment: @Laura you can think also in graphical way, then it would be much more simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $f(x)=10\sqrt[3]{x/5}$ and $g(x)=11\sqrt{x/5}$.
You get something like this
[image]

You can easily come up with the same type of plot if $f''$ and $g''$ are positive

Answer (score 0):

No.
Take, for example,
$$
f(x) = 10 - \frac{2}{5}(x-5)^2,
\qquad
g(x) = \frac{11}{5}\, x.
$$
(If you like, you can slightly modify $g$ to be strictly concave.)